# Can my edit be approved before the post is locked?

Tags: discussion

I [suggested this edit](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/42966) to correct grammar, before it was approved by 1 member but was automatically rejected because of a moderator's lock. As it "has historical significance" and can still be seen, wouldn't my edit help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of that edit was superfluous and didn't really change what was being said besides for the last paragraph which was completely removed.  When reviewing the edit the post was obviously off topic and the edit even removing that did not change that.

Part of the reason for the lock on top of the close was to show the original state of the question when it was answered which the edit taking out the last paragraph would alter.